# Sharepoint 2013 List version History

Tags: 2013, version-history, version

I am creating a solution with SharePoint 2013 and I have multiple SharePoint list. Each list has a few rich text edit box. Is there a way for the user to compare what has been changed between the versions? 
I know you can see some of the details under version history but I can’t compare two blocks of text and see the differences. In particular version history doesn’t display the full text if the text is long.
 Is there a way to compare two version and see the differences, similar to version history in word.

Answer (score 0):

OOTB I haven't heard of a way to compare 2 list items, but here's blog post on a possible development solution. It's compares selected items in a list using the Object Model.

http://www.sharepointbreak.com/2013/02/25/sharepoint-2010-compare-selected-list-items-using-object-model-javascript-and-jquery/